# C++ create new exceptions by inheriting from the std::exception

Tags: c++, class, c++11, exception

Hi I have a c++ assignment in which I need to create my own exceptions. My exception class has to inherit from the std::exception and 2 other classes need to derive from that one. The way I have it right now it actually compiles and works pretty much ok. But when the exception is thrown I get e.g.:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'stack_full_error'
  what():  The stack is full!
Aborted (core dumped)

I am very confused about this matter and unfortunately I could not find much help on the web or in my books. My header is something like the following:

```
class stack_error : public std::exception
{
 public:
  virtual const char* what() const throw();
  stack_error(string const& m) throw(); //noexpect;
  ~stack_error() throw();
  string message;
 private:
};

class stack_full_error : public stack_error
{
 public:
  stack_full_error(string const& m) throw();
  ~stack_full_error() throw();
  virtual const char* what() const throw();
};

class stack_empty_error : public stack_error
{
 public:
  stack_empty_error(string const& m) throw();
  ~stack_empty_error() throw();
  virtual const char* what() const throw();
};
```

and my implementation is:

```
stack_error::stack_error(string const& m) throw()
: exception(), message(m)
{
}

stack_error::~stack_error() throw()
{  
}

const char* stack_error::what() const throw()
{
  return message.c_str();
}

stack_full_error::stack_full_error(string const& m) throw() 
  : stack_error(m)
{   
}

stack_full_error::~stack_full_error() throw()
{

}

const char* stack_full_error::what() const throw()
{
  return message.c_str();
}

stack_empty_error::stack_empty_error(string const& m) throw() 
  : stack_error(m)
{   
}

stack_empty_error::~stack_empty_error() throw()
{

}

const char* stack_empty_error::what() const throw()
{
  return message.c_str();
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you catching the exception?

Comment: The code you posted looks mostly working: the constructors should all have the `throw()` specification removed because each one of them actually _can_ throw an exception! I don't think there is a reason to make the `std::string` a `public` member, either, and it is surely sufficient to override `what()` just in the base class. Can you show the code where you actually catch the exception?

Comment: [Please consider using `virtual` inheritance](http://www.boost.org/libs/exception/doc/using_virtual_inheritance_in_exception_types.html) when creating your own exception types. Also, if `stack_error` inherits from [`runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) instead of `exception` you won't need the `string` member variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that I had forgotten to change my "catch" and I was still looking to catch an std::out_of_range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually catch your exception:

```
try
{
    throw stack_full_error("Stack is full!");
} catch(stack_full_error& ex)
{
    std::cout << ex.what();
}
```

Comment: Whoever invented exceptions isn't very high on my list of most respected people. Why can't there just be a return value that indicates something happened?

Comment: @BWG This would require hacky return types. You can provide detailed information about the error using exceptions. Moreover, you can catch *any* exceptions without explicitly checking through all possible ones.

Comment: @danijar I guess it sort of makes sense. If enough people do it, it has to be right, eh? It just really gets me when I could just use the return value, but I have to go through all that exception handling crap.

Comment: @BWG Exceptions are self-documenting. You would have to consult documentation to find the meaning of return codes, what functions you need to check the return codes of, etc. It can be tiring fast.

Comment: @BWG: Return codes return an error locally -- exceptions can move up the stack. The guts of your algorithm probably can't deal with an out of memory situation, but the upper levels of the app may be able to.

Comment: @BWG: Exceptions are for exceptional situation. Return values are for normal operation. In many cases a return value is appropriate, namely when dealing with some failure state is a fundamental part of the way you use the interface. Exceptions are for the things you *don't* want to deal with right there and then.

Comment: @KerrekSB That seems like an appropriate use.

Comment: @BWG Well, if you program C, you have your error return values. The entire linux kernel is written without a single exception (as it's written in C). And know that you are not alone in your dislike for exceptions, this is one of the many reasons some people prefer C over C++. Personally, I prefer C++ in general, but I consider exceptions harmful, not because of their syntax, but because of the way they skip unrelated code. Worse than a `goto`...

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that I had forgotten to change my "catch" and I was still looking to catch an std::out_of_range.

Comment: @cmaster Hey, why are you hating on `goto`'s? Just kidding, just kidding.

Comment: @BWG One day, a time will come when you will find something is clearly broken but without any error message and you will spend sweet time checking return values from those hundreds of calls written without error checking, because - hey, you have never seen those return an error before in your whole career as a programmer. Never except today. ;)

Comment: @BWG Interestingly, the Linux kernel and many other C code bases use `goto` for error handling in order to jump to cleanup code. And this is considered best practice in C whereas in C++ with exceptions your cleanup is done automatically by destructors of local objects.